# I am trying to change cut and paste to copy and paste and delete using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code and it seems to be almost what I need.  Is there a way to make it copy paste and delete the source instead of just showing a  message box?  I use worksheets that have links to another worksheet and if I use cut and paste I get a #REF error.

Thanks

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
ByVal Target As Excel.Range)


Public NewRange As String

Select Case Application.CutCopyMode
Case Is = False
'do nothing
Case Is = xlCopy
'do nothing
Case Is = xlCut

MsgBox "Please DO NOT Cut and Paste. Use Copy and Paste; then delete the source."
Application.CutCopyMode = False 'clear clipboard and cancel cut
End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`, you will paste the value and not the formula so the reference to the other sheet won't exist. This means you do not have to delete any references to other sheets.

For this to work properly, just update the "Sheet2" and "A1" references in `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
  
  Public NewRange As String

  Select Case Application.CutCopyMode
  Case Is = False
    'do nothing
  Case Is = xlCopy
    'do nothing
  Case Is = xlCut
    MsgBox "Please DO NOT Cut and Paste. Use Copy and Paste; then delete the source."
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False 'clear clipboard and cancel cut
  End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like it should work.  But, I keep getting errors.  I changed  .range to  a range of cells on the worksheet I type / copy and paste  values in:

Comment: When you copy a range of cells, you would paste them to a single cell and it would do the rest. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Run time error 10004 : paste special of range class failed.   Stops on this line. Worksheets("Data_Entry").Range("A20").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues                   I wrote some code to update the links on the other worksheets when I went to t them.  
 Also I'm not sure if dragging cells to another location is cut and paste and if that could be handled.

Comment: Is your worksheet named "Data Sheet" or "Data_Sheet"? Spaces don't need to be replaced. They are wrapped in quotation marks and VBA knows what to do :)